# ¿Porque me sale este error en mi algoritmo? N = int(input()) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0 2'

Tags: python, python-3.x

¡Hola amigos programadores! estaba practicando y me he quedado en este ejercicio porque no lo apruebo sin que me salga este error. Les muestro mi codigo a ver si me pueden ayudar.

```
N = 0
M = 0
nacionalwin = 0
medellinwin = 0
empates = 0

while N != -1 and  M != -1:
    N = int(input())
    M = int(input())
    if N > M and M < N:
        nacionalwin = nacionalwin + 1
        print("GANO NACIONAL")
    elif M > N and N < M:
        medellinwin = medellinwin + 1
        print("GANO MEDELLIN")
    elif N == M and M == N:
        empates = empates + 1
        print("EMPATE")
print("NACIONAL GANO: ",nacionalwin, "PARTIDO(S)")
print("MEDELLIN GANO: ",medellinwin, "PARTIDO(S)")
print("CANTIDAD DE EMPATES: ",empates)
if nacionalwin > medellinwin:
    print("CAMPEON NACIONAL")
elif medellinwin > nacionalwin:
    print("CAMPEON MEDELLIN")
else: print("NO HAY CAMPEON EN ANTIOQUIA")
```

Comment: Tienes que ingresar cada valor separado con un Enter

Answer (score 2):

Esto es debido a que estas intentando enviar los dos valores en una sola linea cuando deberias enviarlos aparte, si deseas tomar ambos valores en una sola linea te recomiendo el metodo .split() el cual permite tomar valores en una misma linea tomando los espacios como punto de diferencia entre un dato y otro, te dejo un ejemplo para tu programa:

```
# Tomando dos valores al tiempo
N, M = input("Ingresa los dos valores: ").split()
N = int(N)
M = int(M)
print("Nacional numero: ", N)
print("Medellin numero: ", M)
print()
```

Comment: Tambien se puede hacer `numeros = [int(num) for num in input("Ingresa los dos valores: ").split()]` y esto retorna una lista de todos los números convertidos a entero

Comment: @DavidsDvm  Muchas gracias, lo probe asi y me funciono full

Answer (score -1):

Buenas ese error es porque con el int(input()) solo metes numeros enteros , si quieres utilizar decimales utiliza el float(input()) por ejemplo.

```
N = 0
M = 0
nacionalwin = 0
medellinwin = 0
empates = 0

while N != -1 and  M != -1:
    N = float(input())
    M = float(input())
    if N > M and M < N:
      nacionalwin = nacionalwin + 1
      print("GANO NACIONAL")
    elif M > N and N < M:
      medellinwin = medellinwin + 1
      print("GANO MEDELLIN")
    elif N == M and M == N:
      empates = empates + 1
      print("EMPATE")
print("NACIONAL GANO: ",nacionalwin, "PARTIDO(S)")
print("MEDELLIN GANO: ",medellinwin, "PARTIDO(S)")
print("CANTIDAD DE EMPATES: ",empates)
if nacionalwin > medellinwin:
  print("CAMPEON NACIONAL")
elif medellinwin > nacionalwin:
  print("CAMPEON MEDELLIN")
else: print("NO HAY CAMPEON EN ANTIOQUIA")
```

Comment: No hay decimales involucrados en esta historia. No aparece ningun "." o ",". Cambiar `int` por `float` no soluciona el problema.